# SpecFlow - The type already contains a definition for 'testRunner'

Tags: c#, specflow

I was getting the following compiler error after having created a brand new feature file:

The type already contains a definition for 'testRunner'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue I had was caused because I had copied a feature file and left the Feature line in from the previous file, this confused the compiler.

To clarify, I include before and after examples below:

Before:

```
Feature: CopiedFromPreviousFile
```

After:

```
Feature: NewFileName
```

Comment: To clarify, Specflow uses the feature title to generate the name of the class which holds the actual tests. So when you have two features with the same title, two classes with the same name are generated and hey presto 'type already defined' error!

Comment: Just to add a similar scenario for people searching for this error: for me this was caused by spaces in the Feature name e.g. My Feature rather than MyFeature.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that Specflow generated a second ***.feature.cs** file for the same feature, which resulted in the same error. Only one **feature.cs** file should be linked for each **feature file**, but sometimes specflow **generates a second feature.cs file when refactorings are made**.

To resolve it **I've deleted the duplicated feature.cs file** generated by specflow for the given feature.